# System.NotSuportedException : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#

I am getting this exception on my server -

```
string fullnamepath = @"https://cental222.intra.abc.com/gbs/TestArea/Destination/SUP000001
    /20050205-01-0005-001/bot.pdf";
    Aspose.pdf.Document doc = new Aspose.pdf.Document(fullnamepath);//This line gives error
System.NotSuportedException : The given path's format is not supported
```

I even tried Path.Combine(Filepath, filename); // it also gives same error

What i am missing ?

Comment: You're specifying a URL rather than a file path?

Comment: URL cant be specified ?

Comment: Try downloading the file from the url to a local file and then open that.

Comment: _URL cant be specified?_ [docs](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/pdf/aspose.pdf/document/constructors/6) say this method "Just init Document using filename". So that - and the exception message - suggests that you need a local file.

Comment: You may find that there is a comparable call that takes a URL.  Look in the docs - no guarantee though.

Comment: Some day networks will be just as safe and reliable as disk drives.  At the rate it is going, I however doubt I'll be alive to witness that day.  Use WebClient.DownloadFile() until then.  Not exactly something you'd favor on a server btw, do consider mapping a file share on an intranet.  IT staff can help you.

Comment: Why my post is downvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the file as your program cannot access the file on the URL, so you would need to download it to your own machine, and then specify the path relative to your own machine,

```
    @"...path to file/bot.pdf
```

EDIT #1 
Your program assumes that the path you gave above exists on your system, whereas it actually exists online.